# My function returns String but I can not parse it ? any idea why?

Tags: ios, json, swift, function, class

I have craeted a class called `db_conn` and inside this calass I have the following functions :

```
public func login (email : String , password : String ) -> String  {
    var result = ""
    let url = URL(string: API.url_login.rawValue)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in


        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("\(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        result = String(responseString!)
        //print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
    }
    task.resume()


    return result
}
```

and then in my login viewController class I try to use it like ==>

```
 @IBAction func login_button_action(_ sender: UIButton) {

       let email = email_text.text
       let passw0rd = password_text.text


        if (email != "" && passw0rd != ""){
            let db_connect = db_conn()
            if  (db_connect.login(email: email!, password: passw0rd!) == nil ){

                print("it's empty ")

            }else {

                print("not empty \(db_connect.login(email: email!, password: passw0rd!))")

            }


        }else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Dont leave any of the spaces blank , they all must be filled up , try again ! ", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

when I run the project it says that the value for `db_connect.login(email: email!, password: passw0rd!)` is not empty but it doesnt print it out . 
(However in my db_conn calss I can easily print the `responseString` and I get the returned JSON in String format . 
Any idea where am I making my mistake ? And how can I possibly fix it ?

Comment: Please learn about asynchronous processing.

Comment: "However in my db_conn calss I can easily print the responseString and I get the returned JSON in String format": Could you add a print before `return result`, and check that it is printed BEFORE `result = String(responseString!)`. You are missing the asynchronous logic here.

Answer (score 1):

Making a network request with `URLSession` runs asynchronously, which means that iOS put it onto a background thread and continues the current thread immediately before the download is finished. Therefore, when you `return result`, it's still an empty string. What you probably want to do is pass a completion closure to your `login` method, and call that with the relevant data when it's finished downloading

Comment: Thanks for your responce I can some how understand what you suggested but I have no idea how to do it . my understanding is to to the ` task = URLSession ...... ` inside my login function but how to pass it back and forth ? I am trying to stick to the oop concept ;)

Comment: [Here's a blog post that can help get you started with something like this](https://www.bobthedeveloper.io/blog/completion-handlers-in-swift-with-bob)